# Align LinearLayout inside a RelativeLayout issue

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

How can i align the "LoginBox" LinearLayout to its parent (that is a RelativeLayout) both at left/right and bottom? I tried to insert:

```
 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```

but it doesn't do the trick! Infact the linearlayout is not properly aligned to the margin of the screen! :(

This is my XML code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/sfondologin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
   android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:src="@drawable/stemmatrasparente" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LoginBox"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/usernametxt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@drawable/sfondobuttonedittext"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/usericon"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:typeface="sans" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.18" >
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/passwordtxt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@drawable/sfondobuttonedittext"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/lockicon"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:typeface="sans" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.29" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/forgotpass"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="Dimenticato la password?"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textColorHint="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/value12dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/loginbtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@drawable/sfondobuttonlogin"
            android:text="Login"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/registerbtn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center|end"
        android:background="@drawable/sfondobuttonrb2"
        android:text="Registrati"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

</LinearLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:layout_weight="0.01" 
    android:background="#00000000">
</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thank you in advance!

EDIT: 
The first screen is what i have now! While the second, edited with photoshop (sorry), is what i want to get!

[image: Layout to edit]
[image: Layout edited]

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to achieve - are you trying to make the layout fill the parent or are you trying to center it? aligning to the left and right won't work because you're trying to pull the start and ends in different directions.

Comment: try to use Linear Layout as parent then Make child for Relative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove

```
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

these lines form your outermost ReletiveLayout.
Thats it!

Comment: Great!! You save my time :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom">

<Button
        android:id="@+id/registerbtn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center|end"
        android:background="@drawable/sfondobuttonrb2"
        android:text="Registrati"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I put a LinearLayout before the button, and added android:gravity="bottom" to the LinearLayout. This should do it.

Answer (score 1):

Remove your top layout's right, left and bottom padding:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/sfondologin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
```